# SharePoint 2010 custom workflow - Adding approver to existing approvers list

Tags: 2010, workflow

I was asked to add a new user to the list of existing approvers in a SP2010 custom approval workflow.

The workflow was created long back. I don't have the access to the code for that.

Now, I am not sure, how/where to look for a group or list of users where i can add my new users to.

Can somebody point me in right direction ? Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Additional Info. :

1) The workflow in question is attached to a content type, which is used in a custom list. 
2) I can see a .wsp file with the same name as that of workflow name in the solution gallery of the site collection.

Thanks.

---

I found out that there are names of few people added as approvers in the SPD workflow.
[image]

Now, if i add one or two more users here and save my changes. Will they start getting the approval request. Or I will require to publish/deploy the workflow again.

Comment: you want to add approver for site? which will be further part of workflow approver.

Comment: Anuja, can you clarify "Approver for site" ?

Comment: Two questions - 1) when you say 'custom approval workflow', do you mean it was created in Visual Studio and added to the site as a feature? 2) Does the workflow use a hard-coded list of approvers or a SharePoint/AD group?

Comment: 1) I am not sure as I don't have the code. The only thing I was able to dig-out was that the workflow in question is attached to a content type, which is used in a custom list. And yes I can see a .wsp file with the same in the solution gallery of the site collection.                                                2) Again the answer is i don't know.....bcz i don't have the code.

Comment: If there's a matching WSP file, it's most likely a VS workflow added as a solution. I can't imagine any SP developer worth their salt using a hard-coded list of approvers, but you never know.

Comment: Your best bet is to get a list of the existing approvers and then compare their group memberships. When you find the group that includes them all, it's probably just a matter of adding the new approver to that group. It could be a group in SharePoint OR AD, however.

Comment: I downloaded the .wsp file and extracted its content. It has Elements.xml, Feature.xml, manifest.xml, Workflowname.xoml, Workflowname.xoml.rules........ So, it seems to be a SPD workflow.

Comment: @Omegacron It's what you don't want to hear, the list of users is hard-coded :)

Comment: Ugh. Shame on whoever did that. If you get a chance to modify or re-do the workflow, you should definitely change it to use a group in SharePoint or AD.